# Docker error: QStandardPaths: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1 Could not connect to any X display

Tags: docker, ros, ubuntu-22.04

I just started using docker and I need to use it to run ros melodic. I am currently on ubuntu 22.04.

The dockerfile I am using to create an image is the following:

```
FROM osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common \
    ros-melodic-catkin \
    python-catkin-tools \
    python-pip \
    openssh-client \
    net-tools \
    ros-melodic-rqt-multiplot \
    x11-apps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I build it with `docker build -t e-go:latest .`. Everythigh looks good so far.
To run the container I made a bash file:

```
#! /bin/bash

xhost +local:
docker run -it --rm \
--net=host \
--user=$(id -u) \
--env="ROS_HOME=/home/$USER/.ros" \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
-e QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native \
-e XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR \
--env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
-e CONTAINER_NAME=ros-melodic-dev \
-e USER=$USER \
--workdir=/home/$USER \
-v "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix" \
-v "/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
-v "/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
-v "/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
-v "/etc/sudoers.d:/etc/sudoers.d:ro" \
-v "/home/$USER/:/home/$USER/" \
-v "/run/user/1000:/run/user/1000" \
-v "$HOME/.ros:/home/$USER/.ros" \
--device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri \
--name=ros-melodic-dev \
--privileged \
e-go:latest
```

After it in the first terminal window inside the container I run `roscore` and it works fine. In a new terminal I run `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`, then to test the GUI in docker I run `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`. This last command gives me the following error:

```
QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 0 instead of 1000
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I tried almost all the suggestions online, but nothing worked. Another thing I tried was to run the container as root user with `--user root`, in this case the error is slightly different:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

If you have any ideas it would be very helpful. If you need more information, I'll be happy to provide it.

I tried to change `xhost +local:` to `xhost +local:docker` or `xhost +local:root`.

I added

```
--ipc=host \
--env=QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 \
--env=XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY \
-v /dev:/dev \
```

To solve problems with X servers (did not worked).
And many other test that I don't remember anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try docker-compose file instead of bash (or you can translate back to bash command)

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file I successfully use with GUI located in the same folder as Dockerfile:

```
version: "3.0"
services: 
  geo:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile
    image: robot
    container_name: robot
    restart: always
    # runtime: nvidia

    # Both needed for topic communication between machines to work
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host

    environment:
      # DISPLAY: host.docker.internal:0.0  # For Windows
      - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
      - QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
      - LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
      - USER=root

    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      # General
      - ..:/root/ros_ws/robot_ws
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent # Forward local machine SSH key to docker
      - ~/.gitconfig:/etc/gitconfig # Forward git config
      - /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/:/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ # Forward ssh config
```

O you could try removing `-v "/run/user/1000:/run/user/1000"` from your setup I remember this line was problematic for other reasons

If I remember correctly **on Windows** something as simple as this was enough for GUI but it probably won't work on Ubuntu:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=host --name robot -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0 -e LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0 robot bash
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the GUI works (`Ubuntu 20.04`) if I just:

- run this in the same terminal: `xhost +`
- and then add the following options to the `docker run` command:
  `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` and also `--volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw"` if it's not working only with the previous ones.

Not sure what might be the problem in your case, but I'm thinking it might be the missing `--device` option.